# How to know which line (date) is missing in a text file in R?

Tags: r

I have a text file `dat` that contains data (daily values) for two years 2008-2009.The total number of lines is 730 but it should be 731 (because 2008 has 366) so there is one date missing (line). I wonder how I can I know which date is missing?
there should be one line (row) per day

The file:

```
head(dat)
     Year day   valu 
61322 2008   1    0.301 
61346 2008   2    0.285 
61370 2008   3    0.272 
61394 2008   4    0.253
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is surprisingly complicated. But maybe I’ve made a logical error here, and there’s a much more straightforward solution.

First, some helpers:

```
days_in_year = function (year)
    1 : (if (is_leap_year(year)) 366 else 365)

is_leap_year = function (year)
    year %% 4 == 0 && (year %% 100 != 0 || year %% 400 == 0)
```

Now we can generate a full list of days for each year, and see whether these are all present in your `data.frame`:

```
years = c(2008, 2009)
years = setNames(years, years)
full_years = lapply(years, days_in_year)

missing_days = lapply(years, function (y) which(is.na(match(full_years[[as.character(y)]], subset(dat, Year == y)$day))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
dfDate = with(dat, as.Date(day, origin="2008-01-01"))

yearDates = seq(as.Date("2008-01-01"),as.Date("2009-12-31"), by="days")

yearDates[!yearDates %in% dfDate]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count the fields in the file with `count.fields()`

```
txt <- "Year day   valu 
61322 2008   1    0.301

61370 2008   3    0.272 
61394 2008   4    0.25"
```

We can set the starting line to 2 with `skip = 1` so that the header row won't appear in the result, and `blank.lines.skip = FALSE` to get back any blank rows (shown as zero).  You can spot any other discrepancies by taking the difference from 4.

```
(cf <- count.fields(textConnection(txt), skip = 1, blank.lines.skip = FALSE))
# [1] 4 0 4 4
which(cf == 0)
# [1] 2
```

So now you can deduce that the missing date may be on the second line. In your case, running `count.fields()` on the file should tell you where the missing line is.

```
count.fields("file.dat", skip = 1, blank.lines.skip = FALSE)
```

There are also other useful arguments

```
> args(count.fields)
function (file, sep = "", quote = "\"'", skip = 0, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, 
    comment.char = "#")
```

Comment: This shows *that* rows are missing (which OP already knows), not *which* rows are missing, unless there happens to be a blank line in the input in place of the missing row.

Comment: Well they go in order, so you can deduce which ones are missing `== 0`

Comment: Right, **assuming** there’s a blank line where the missing record should be.

Comment: Right, but you can also look for a discrepancy in the number of fields. If there is a missing date but the rest of the row is there, we'll see 3 instead of 4 (minus the header row)

Comment: I’m still not convinced that this is going to help OP since I assume he’s got a complete table, just with one complete row deleted) but it’s a very interesting technique which I didn’t know, so definitely a helpful answer.